# What is the difference between present perfect progressive and present perfect?

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

I learn that the difference between present perfect progressive and present perfect is the fact that present perfect means that the event occurred in the past is just completed. and present perfect progressive means the event occurred in the past is now going on and will continue to go on in some amount of time in the near future.
Am I right?

Comment: *I've been playing pub darts every Friday for years. But the only local pub for miles around has just closed for lack of customers, so that's the end of that.* It's not an absolutely unbreakable rule that ***present perfect progressive** means the event is **now going on, and will continue**.*

Comment: Related: [Can present perfect be used instead of present perfect progressive?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/103496/) [The Present Perfect Progressive and the Simple Present Perfect](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/29028/)

Answer (score 2):

Actually the present perfect has several uses.  Sometimes it indicates a recently completed event:

> The race **has finished**.

Sometimes it indicates a life experience:

> I **have visited** Japan many times.

Sometimes (with additional information) it indicates an ongoing, periodic situation:

> I **have eaten** oatmeal every morning for ten years

In contrast, the present perfect progressive always indicates an ongoing situation, either periodic or continuous:

> I **have been eating** oatmeal every morning for ten years.
>
> He **has been practicing** guitar for three hours.
>
> That church **has been standing** in the village since the Middle Ages.

While it does create some *expectation* that the event will continue into the future, as FumbleFingers says in his comment, there is no *guarantee* of this.

> I **have been eating** oatmeal every morning for ten years, but I think today I'll try cereal instead.

Answer (score 0):

the difference between the present perfect and the present perfect progressive is that:

The present perfect is mainly used with verbs that describes states of things called "stative verbs", for example:to hear, feel, like, hate, belong, have.... and so on.
the present perfect is used when the action took place in the past in a period of time which still valid up to now, as to say I have posted a letter to my friend, the action is completed but the time is still valid. when you have posted the letter? I have posted the letter this week, this month this year, to day and so on, the present perfect is used with so called time connectors for example: for, since, over the years, this week, this month, this century....

In contrast to present perfect, **the present perfect progressive** is used mainly with the verbs of action I have down voted because the example of the church I think is wrong the church has stood since middle ages because in this case the verb is considered as stative verb. when you use the present perfect progressive it comes to the mind that something keeps repeating  over a period of time up to now.for example: to drive, walk, teach.. and so on. I have been driving since I was 12, that means you drive then you go home then you drive again and again....

note that some verbs are both stative and dynamic.